# Are there ways of testing Google Analytics demographic data collection?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been working with Google Analytics, and while I have all the necessary settings in the right configuration to collect demographic information, I'm not seeing anything. Other information (active users, geographic info) is showing up as I'd expect, so it's not that everything is broken. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to test the demographic data collection, to ensure that it's not just that users are blocking that data (it is a very low traffic site). Other tips are also appreciated in case I'm missing something else that could be causing this to happen. Thanks very much for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the demographics data in the reports takes a lot of hits, because they are based on a sample of total sessions.

Anyway, you can check if you have activated them by looking in the browser network if you are also sending hits to **doubleclick** as well as Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks so much Michele! I'm going to assume that this is a result of just having a very low number of total sessions. We (I believe) are not sending hits to DoubleClick, and this is a fairly low priority project for me at the moment so I'll likely forego looking into that.